# shutting down all machines on network at 19:45

Tags: windows, batch-file, shutdown

Wondering if someone could just point me in the right direction, I created a batch file and added it to GPO, to shutdown all pc's at 19:45, however it doesn't seem to be executing correctly,

```
@echo off
:s
if %time%==19:45:00.00 (c:windowssystem32shutdown.exe /s /f)
goto :s
```

Comment: Everyone will hate you for this script. This ramps an entire CPU core up to full on my machine, with its infinite loop. Fans spinning up, laptop batteries running down, actual work being slowed down. Ughhhhh. Setup a scheduled task to run at 19:45 and do the shutdown.

Comment: first: your loop is eating all of your CPU ressources. Never build a loop without some idletime (like `timeout 1`). second: there is a high chance to miss the correct time. Better use `GEQ` instead of `==` (see `if /?`)

Comment: Why don't you shut them down from the server? (`shutdown /m computername`)

Comment: @Stephan's idea of using `GEQ` is good, but I would also avoid the `goto :s` in case the time matches in order to not fire multiple `shutdown` commands...

Comment: There are the backslashes missing in the path to `shutdown.exe`; I assume this happened when copying the code into this question post...

Comment: @aschipfl: additional shutdown commands will be rejected. Althouh avoiding it is a good programming habit, it's not really neccessary.